# HBase connection is null , missing dependencies , configuration or some properties

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to connect to HBase server running on different server from a linux client and i get below error . The code works fine from my windows laptop and I am able to connect to Hbase server and get results. I think I am missing some dependencies jar for my linux server because when i added hbase-client jar it worked from my laptop, which indicates my code logic is correct. All of configuration is being picked up correctly as I have verified it from  my laptop. Please provide some suggestion. I am passing hbase-site.xml,core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml in my resources . My port and zookeeper qurom is correct. My kerberose code works fine.

**Code:** connection is returned as null :-(

```
this.conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    this.conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", zookeeperQuorum);
    this.conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", port);
    this.conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-secure");
    //this.conf.set("hbase.client.retries.number", Integer.toString(35));
    //this.conf.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", Integer.toString(20000));
    //this.conf.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry", Integer.toString(1));
    this.conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    this.conf.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    this.conf.set("hbase.master.kerberos.principal", userName);
    this.conf.set("user.name", userName);
try {
    this.connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(conf);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.msoa.hbase.client</groupId>
<artifactId>simpleHBase</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>HbaseWrite</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
<plugins>
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>simpleHBase.actionClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>       
  </plugin>    
</plugins>
</build>
<!--  added for dev box  -->
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>repo.hortonworks.com</id>
  <name>Hortonworks HDP Maven Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<!--  end dev box -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.7.0_60</version>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <!--   adding to test on beam -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  add protocol for beam test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Error:**

> java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:416)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:309)
>           at simpleHBase.HBaseConnectionFactory.(HBaseConnectionFactory.java:99)
>           at simpleHBase.HBaseClient.(HBaseClient.java:26)
>           at simpleHBase.actionClass.main(actionClass.java:118) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:414)
>           ... 4 more Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:69)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:857)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.(HConnectionManager.java:662)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create local dir /data0/hadoop/hbase/local/jars, DynamicClassLoader
>   failed to init
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DynamicClassLoader.(DynamicClassLoader.java:94)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.(ProtobufUtil.java:201)
>           ... 14 more

Answer (score 1):

At the end of exception there is a line like,

"Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create local dir /data0/hadoop/hbase/local/jars,"

can you please check the permission, whether user has permission to create the directory at the specified location or not.

Comment: That was the problem, as a user i was not allowed on that server so couldn't really check if that dir had permission to the userid i am using . i changed hbase-site.xml : tmp.local.dir to point to /tmp/ and it worked . thanks for looking into it  .